# xls file corrupted after updating existing xls file using jxl

Tags: java, jxl

I'm updating the content in the 'Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)' using 'jxl jar'. Everything is fine with the code. But when open after update, it is showing "We find a problem with the content in data.xls". 
The file is being corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't close the operation. To close the operation, add **YourWorkbook.write();** and **YourWorkbook.close();** after those addCell(); methods.

Comment: There is no problem with the resource closing. Everything is fine regarding resource closing.